# Automation anywhere RPA

Tags: sql-server, parameter-passing, automationanywhere

I did not find how to make use of add parameter when we use DB-sql commands in the process of using run stored procedure in AA client widget.
I used the parameter but could not find where to assign value to this parameter in the wizard.
Please share an example if possible with snapshot.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
(
@p1 VARCHAR(50),
@p2 INT 
)
```

Option (1)
You can take database command and select “Run Stored Procedure”
In procedure name you can pass parameter as variable like this

```
sp1('$a1$','$a2$')
```

a1 and a2 are variables added in variable manager. (right side menu of client editor widget)

If param1 value is integer you can pass it like sp1($param1$,'$param2$').

For string parameter you need to put single quote.

Image for option (1) ($a1$ is variable, 2 is fix integer value: p1 will get value of a1, p2 will get 2)

[image]

Option (2)

Another option to provide static value in stored procedure, select Add Parameter option

Procedure Name: sp1

Add Parameter(s)

Enter parameter value (Value of param1) and type and click on Add.

Image for option (2) (p1 will get test123, p2 will get 1)

[image]

Comment: Hi  i am looking for the second scenario which you explained but there is no option to provide value for those parameters.Please tell me how do i assign value to the parameter testp1 its value which is of type INT.

Comment: I have added appropriate images.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you.Suppose i have SP -getemployee which expects an ID of int type as parameter,so as per your explaination i will send it in add parameter as( parameter name-ID type-Input ),but where do i assign value for ID = 3 ??

Comment: you need to pass parameter value and parameter type (i.e. 3 and input). You don't need to specify parameter name, you need to keep it in sequence.

Comment: We are running a stored procedure sp1('$a1$','$a2$') but we are getting a syntax error or access violation

Comment: You can check your variables defined properly and assigned proper value. You can check your database connection.

Comment: Thanks it works I  wrongly declare the parameters in both the procedure name and add parameters..

Comment: Good to know it helped, kindly up vote so that it may help others.